# c# XML DTD validation. ENTITY is an unexpected token

Tags: c#, xml, validation, dtd

Im trying to validate an XML file using a .DTD but it gives me the following error.

> 'ENTITY' is an unexpected token. The expected token is 'DOCTYPE'. Line 538, position 3.

```
        public static void Validate(string xmlFilename, string schemaFilename)
    {
        XmlTextReader r = new XmlTextReader(xmlFilename);
        XmlValidatingReader validator = new XmlValidatingReader(r);
        validator.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

        XmlSchemaCollection schemas = new XmlSchemaCollection();
        schemas.Add(null, schemaFilename);


        validator.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler);

        try
        {
            while (validator.Read())
            { }
        }
        catch (XmlException err)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            validator.Close();
        }
    }
```

The DTD im using to validate = http://www.editeur.org/onix/2.1/reference/onix-international.dtd

I hope someone can help me thanks!

Comment: The DTD you are trying to parse against has an error.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is a really old question, but for anyone else struggling with this problem, here's what I did.

I gave up trying to validate with the DTD.

Instead, I ended up using the onix 2.1 xsd available at http://www.editeur.org/15/Previous-Releases/#R%202.1%20Downloads. I had to set the default namespace:

```
var nt = new NameTable();
var ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
ns.AddNamespace(string.Empty, "http://www.editeur.org/onix/2.1/reference");
var context = new XmlParserContext(null, ns, null, XmlSpace.None);
```

and then when loading the xml, turn off DTD parsing (this is using .NET4)

```
var settings = XmlReaderSettings
                {
                    ValidationType = System.Xml.ValidationType.Schema,
                    DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore
                }
using(var reader = XmlReader.Create("path to xml file", settings)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Edit:

Just noticed: your validation type is also set wrong. Try setting it to ValidationType.DTD instead of Schema.

[ValidationType at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.validationtype.aspx)

--

The error means exactly as it states- the DTD that is referenced is not well formed, as DOCTYPE should be present before any other declarations in a DTD.

[Document Type Definition (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition)

[Introduction to DTD (w3schools)](http://www.w3schools.com/DTD/dtd_intro.asp)

You might be able to get around this by downloading a local copy, modifying it to add in the expected root element yourself, and then referencing your edited version in your source.

Comment: I really do not believe the cxml.dtd from cxml.org is invalid?
It throws the exact same message when I try to load for XML validations